# ColladaLoader and progressCallback

Tags: javascript, three.js, loader, collada

What is the correct way of implementing a *loading bar* in `ColladaLoader`?

The source code shows that the loader takes three parameters. One which is a `progressCallback`.

```
progressCallback( { total: length, loaded: request.responseText.length } );
```

If I call a function for the `progressCallback` to display the values, The `total` shows up as null and the `loaded` goes up to 5,200,000.

```
function(callback){    
    console.log(callback.loaded + ' / ' + callback.total);
}
```

How can I attach some sort of a *percentage* of the *loaded elements* using the `ColladaLoader`?

Comment: Are you running a local server? If not, that may be the problem. See https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/How-to-run-things-locally

Comment: @WestLangley I don't have an issue with loading a collada file. I need a way to determine a percentage of loaded elements to display a loading screen with a loading bar. I can't find information on how to use the `progressCallback` function.

Comment: What is the answer to my question?

Comment: @WestLangley Yes, I am running a local server.

Comment: OK. Fair enough. I was able to reproduce your problem when loading as a file. When running a server, your code works for me.

Comment: @WestLangley Since I know the max(5,200,000), I can still get a percentage. My main issue is that the function is called once and jumps from 70% to 100%. I'm looking for a gradual change. Timers don't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source code of `ColladaLoader.js`, it looks like the `progressCallback` function checks the **total amount of characters** in your collada file(5,200,000) and the **amount of characters read**.

You can get a percentage by using

```
var percent = Math.round(callback.loaded / callback.total) * 100;
```

Your percentage is jumping from one number to another most likely because it is being called locally or part of the data is cached. If you run this from a server, your percentage will be updated gradually.

WestLangley is correct that the total will only show up on a server or local server and as `null` if opened as file. This is because Ajax sends a request to the server.