# Java script preload contents three.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, three.js

Simply i would like to pre-load contents with a bar or what ever really in my three.js project or JavaScript either way should be fine, im familiar with action-script to do this task but cant seem to manage this in javascript:

Heres the code:

```
    var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader(); 
    loader.load( 'myobject.obj', 'myobject.mtl', function ( object ) {
    for(k in object.children){
        object.children[k].position.z =-5;
        console.log("position Changed");
     }
     scene.add( object );
     console.log("the item is loaded");
```

I have looked at the loader examples to do with three.js sample files but i really dont follow it to well, is there way to check the file size vs file bytes received  and implement it with the above, i have tried but returns under-fine.    Jquery is also  welcomed

Comment: try: `loader.load( url, mtlurl, onLoad, onProgress, onError )` and see the related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21655100/colladaloader-and-progresscallback

Comment: I have been trying to work with this but it fails to actually display the model, object function does not execute as expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have similar problem. I have created an `Array` to preload and store all the objects in there. Passed and returned the `currentId`, to be able to store them after that. In `Objects3DListJson` I put the info for the `Paths`

```
for (var curobj = 0; curobj < Objects3DListJson.length; curobj++) {
    loaderMTL.load(curobj, ObjPath, mtlPath, function (object, currentID) {
        var obj3D = new Obj3D(Objects3DListJson[currentID].ObjectName, object)
        objects3D.push(obj3D);
    }
}
```

Of course I changed `OBJMTLLoader` to return the Current ID. I hope this help you on some way.